# Read out marked files in explorer by context menu entry using batch script

Tags: batch-file, gnuplot, contextmenu

I add an entry in the context menu in windows to access a small script which allows to plot the marked ascii file with gnuplot.

The script looks like that

```
@echo off
set x_col=-1
set /P x_col=x-column:
if %x_col% LSS 0 goto onetwo 
goto arbitrary 

:onetwo
start wgnuplot.exe -p -e "set datafile separator whitespace; plot '%~nx1' using 1:2 with lines"
exit /b

:arbitrary
set /P y_col=y-column:
start wgnuplot.exe -p -e "set datafile separator whitespace; plot '%~nx1' using %x_col%:%y_col% with lines" 
exit /b
```

That helps me to get a quick overview of the included data. The script is called with the parameter %1 to get the filename of the marked file used as input parameter for gnuplot.

To compare several graphs I want to mark an abritrary number of files and plot the contents all at once in a single graph. For that approach gnuplot just needs a list containing the multiple filenames. However using the script above an own instance of gnuplot is opened for each marked file. That is not what I want. Here the argument %1 just contain the filename of one single file.

So does anybody know how to extract and combine the filenames of the marked files into a "list" using the context menu and a simple script? Is there an other argument than %1 which contains the all marked files.

Answer (score 0):

I believe what you are refering to is `%*`

To Quote http://www.robvanderwoude.com/parameters.php:

```
An easy work-around in NT 4 and later is:

FOR %%A IN (%*) DO (
      ....
      Now your batch file handles %%A instead of %1
      )

No need to use SHIFT anymore.
```

Which you should be able to easily add to your code.

Comment: Thanks that works, but I want to use a context menu entry to call the script even better to do the plots. So I'm one step further: I guess the problem is to define an operator in the command section in the registry (responsible for the context menu entry) which includes all marked files. So far I use as registry entry: `C:\Program Files (x86)\gnuplot\bin\GnuPlotScript.bat "%1" `. However the operator "%1" just transfer a single filename. If I mark more than one file the script is started for each file 
separately. By the way swapping in the registry %1 for %* does not work.